# What is the effect of rsync --block-size on large files?

Tags: networking, rsync, performance, storage

I want to backup a few terabytes of large files (500mb to 1500mb each) to a backup server (BULK storage) via rsync.

For this I use the following command (updated with suggestions from @Gilles):

<del>`rsync  --stats --progress --ignore-existing --recursive --exclude ".*" /from/ /to`</del>

```
rsync --stats --progress  --archive --update --exclude ".*" /from/ /to
```

My transfer speeds are ~40MB/s. I think this speed is limited by the BULK storage system on the other site of the line. (SSD --> 1000mbits/s --> BULK storage)

As I know I will rsync mainly big files, is it useful to specify the block-size for speeding up my transfer? If it does speed up my transfer, will it be reasonably more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--block-size` is a parameter of rsync's delta transfer algorithm, i.e. its partial transfer algorithm based on block checksum. Since you are doing local copies, the delta transfer algorithm is not used, so `--block-size` is ignored.
The delta transfer algorithm gives worse results on local copies (that's why it's off by default), because rsync then needs to read all the files on the destination side. It's useful when disk access on either side is significantly faster than the network connection between the two sides.

40MB/s of file I/O is about 400Mb/s of raw disk I/O considering the filesystem overhead. Are you sure that both sides can sustain more than that?

You should usually use `rsync -a`, to preserve all file modes. For a backup, definitely use `-a`. Add the `-u` flag so as not to waste time copying files that haven't been modified (in addition to `-a`: `-u` isn't useful if you aren't preserving the times).

Comment: This is exactly the complete and explanatory answer I was looking for, thanks. For my understanding, with local do not mean local machine, but local area network (LAN) right?

Comment: @CousinCocaine “Local” means using the filesystem, i.e. when you give a local path to rsync (`/path/to/file` or `relative/path`), as opposed to a remote path (`host:remote/path` over rsh or ssh, or `rsync://host/remote/path` over rsync). Rsync has no way to know whether a remote host is in a LAN. You may want to pass `--whole-file` on a very fast LAN.

Comment: This was unclear and my fault. The BULK filesystem is mounted SMB share. Furthermore, `--whole-file` is useful on a fast lan, but is the default when both the source and destination are specified as local paths (my case).

Comment: would a write to a NFS be local? That is, would --block-size come into action in that case?

Comment: @quimnuss Yes. “Local” in this context means that rsync is not doing the network transmission. If the filesystem is doing a network transmission, that's transparent from rsync's point of view, rsync is just interacting with the local filesystem.